# startService method is called but nothing happens

Tags: android, android-service

I'm trying to start a service from a broadcast, but for some reason my service never gets called.
This is my receiver:

```
private void initReceiver() {
    receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals("telecom.IT.DigiCARE.REC")) {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Intent received from server!");

                byte[] data = intent.getByteArrayExtra("Data");
                String params = intent.getStringExtra("Params");

                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DecodeService.class);
                i.putExtra("Data", data);
                i.putExtra("Params", params);

                startService(i);
            }
        }
    };

    registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("telecom.IT.DigiCARE.REC"));
}
```

This is my service:

```
public class DecodeService extends Service {

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    String params = intent.getStringExtra("Params");
    byte[] data = intent.getByteArrayExtra("Data");

    decodeMessage(params, data);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    String params = intent.getStringExtra("Params");
    byte[] data = intent.getByteArrayExtra("Data");

    decodeMessage(params, data);
    return START_STICKY;
}
}
```

I was expecting the error to be somewhere in the manifest, but I don't see it.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.telecomIT.digicare"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<services
        android:name=".DecodeService"
        android:enabled="true" />
```

It is not because the broadcast doesn't work, because the startService gets called, but then nothing happens..

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing happens"? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: I expect the start method in the service to be called, but that doesn't happen.

Comment: What does your logcat look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the problem.. I had service**s** instead of service.
Strange that that didn't generate a lint error or something.

Answer (score 0):

Your declaration  must be declared after declaration of the  where specify the service package. Try it:

```
        <meta-data <!-- First -->
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <services <!-- Second -->
                android:name=".DecodeService"
                android:enabled="true" />
```